# Use jenkins environment variable in SH script with multiple quote

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I want to use jenkins env variable with SH, but inside multiple quote from `curl`.

Example:

```
script {
  container('deployer') {
    sh "curl -X POST --data-urlencode \"payload={'channel': '#notification-test-devops', 'username': 'Jenkins Build', 'text': '[Blocked Production] ${env.JOB_BASE_NAME} (${env.BRANCH_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}) <${BUILD_URL}|View Build>', 'icon_emoji': ':jenkins:'}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XXX/XXX"
  }
}
```

Current result seems it's not rendered:

```
[Blocked Staging] ${env.JOB_BASE_NAME} (${env.BRANCH_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}) <${BUILD_URL}|View Build>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB2Vs.png)

Expectation:
The jenkins env variable will be rendered in Slack message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after few tries, this is works.

```
container('deployer') {
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
        sh """
            curl -X POST --data-urlencode \"payload={'channel': '#notification-test-devops', 'username': 'Jenkins Build', 'text': \\\"[Blocked Production] ${env.JOB_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}\nCommit ID: ${GIT_COMMIT}\nCommit Message: ${GIT_COMMIT_MSG}\n<${BUILD_URL}|View Build>\\\", 'icon_emoji': ':jenkins:'}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XXX/XXX
        """
    }
}
```

You can ignore the wrapping, because I only use it with [build-user-vars-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to backslash your variables.

Change *${env.BRANCH_NAME}* by *${env.BRANCH_NAME}*

Example :

```
script {
  container('deployer') {
    sh "curl -X POST --data-urlencode \"payload={'channel': '#notification-test-devops', 'username': 'Jenkins Build', 'text': '[Blocked Production] ${env.JOB_BASE_NAME} (${env.BRANCH_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}) <${BUILD_URL}|View Build>', 'icon_emoji': ':jenkins:'}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XXX/XXX"
  }
}
```

Became :

```
script {
  container('deployer') {
    sh "curl -X POST --data-urlencode \"payload={'channel': '#notification-test-devops', 'username': 'Jenkins Build', 'text': '[Blocked Production] \${env.JOB_BASE_NAME} (\${env.BRANCH_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER}) <${BUILD_URL}|View Build>', 'icon_emoji': ':jenkins:'}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XXX/XXX"
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working ```/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/XXX_master@tmp/durable-d97a4e9d/script.sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your message text into double quotes to detect the variables. Give also to your shell block three doubles quotes to no interfer with the doubles others doubles quotes inside the shell block"

```
script {
  container('deployer') {
    sh """
        curl -X POST --data-urlencode \"payload={'channel': '#notification-test-devops', 'username': 'Jenkins Build', 'text': "[Blocked Production] ${env.JOB_BASE_NAME} (${env.BRANCH_NAME} Build number: ${BUILD_NUMBER}) <${BUILD_URL}|View Build>", 'icon_emoji': ':jenkins:'}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XXX/XXX
    """

  }
}
```

Comment: it seems rendered on error output, but there is an error:

```Shell Script -- curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={'channel': '#notification-test-devops', 'username': 'Jenkins Build', 'text': "[Blocked Production] master (master #16) <https://jenkins.XXX.net/job/XXX/job/master/16/|View Build>", 'icon_emoji': ':jenkins:'}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XXX/XXX (self time 589ms)
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/XXX_master@tmp/durable-6305c906/script.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: It seems that the "#" is causing problems. Try it without as my edit.